# Downloading Provisioning Profiles for iOS Dev on Multiple devices

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I'm trying to compile an app that was created by my team but I'm getting these errors:

> Provisioning profile "Developer profile" doesn't include signing
>   certificate "iPhone Developer: person's name (key number)".

and

> Provisioning profile "Adhoc" doesn't include signing certificate
>   "iPhone Distribution: company name (key number)".

I downloaded the provisioning profiles and installed them but I'm still getting these errors. I thought that was all you had to do?

Comment: Ah yes, after clicking the automatic signing and my company it worked -no need to export the key from the creator's mac

Answer (score 0):

Edit profile in apple developer account , save it , download it . now remove last stored one from iphone configuration utilities. Install dowloaded one . it worked for me. Or if still not working then create new certificate then again follow same step as above but select new certificate while editing profile. And download new cert , should remove previous one as it may confuse us :)

Comment: Xcode 8 projects have an option to automatically manage signing. Add your account to Xcode and now you have the option to create an archive using development build instead of Adhoc. If you want to do it the old way you can export developer certificate from Keychain access as p12 file and import it on other macs